# Mongodb query using a nested path based on the value of another property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection with documents like the following:

```
{
   _id : 1,
   code: 1,
   state: "FINISHED",
   history:                                            //Object
      { 'CREATED': { date: xxx , anotherParam: xxx },
        'FINISHED': { date: xxx , anotherParam: xxx }
      }
},
{
   _id : 2,
   code: 1,
   state: "CREATED",
   history:                                            //Object
      { 'CREATED': { date: xxx , anotherParam: xxx }
},
{
   _id : 3,
   code: 2,
   state: "FINISHED",
   history:                                            //Object
      { 'CREATED': { date: xxx , anotherParam: xxx },
        'FINISHED': { date: xxx , anotherParam: xxx }
      }
}
```

What I want to do is a find query in which I sort the documents by the date nested in history whose key is the value of state for each document.

In the previous example, I would sort by the current value of state ( inside the corresponding history key => `"history.VALUE_OF_STATE.date"`.

The challenges is to be able to get FINISHED inside that path based on state value.

E.G: Query all documents where code == 1 and sort by history.VALUE_OF_EACH_DOCUMENT_STATE.date

This should return doc _id 1 and doc _id 2, sorting by date, considering doc 1's date as history.FINISHED.date, and doc 2's date history.CREATED.date

Comment: lets suppose you get the state from the first document , but in next document state can be different ... , on which value you will need to sort then?

Comment: I've updated the question to clear up the problem

Comment: That's going to be a very strange query, why not create a field called `sortingDate` and fill that on write time?

Comment: That would be a valid workaround, I would like to know if what I ask could be done though

Comment: Might be possible, if you move away from subdocuments to array of subdocuments. It'd still be messy and expensive to run (depending on size of your collection)

Comment: how many different possibilities of these states?

Comment: 4 states in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of hard-coding, since you only have 4 possible states:

```
db.states.aggregate([
  { $match: { code: 1 } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      code: 1,
      state: 1,
      history: 1,
      sortingField: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: { $eq: ["$state", "CREATED"] },
              then: "$history.CREATED.date",
            },
            {
              case: { $eq: ["$state", "FINISHED"] },
              then: "$history.FINISHED.date",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: { sortingField: 1 },
  },
]);
```